# WCF Service Hosted in Windows Service running 10x slower than console app

Tags: c#, wcf, performance, windows-services

I have a C# library that does some file processing. I created a console and desktop application that uses the library and processes a 256mb file in about 1min. I then created a WCF service hosted in a windows service which uses the same file processing library yet takes 10x longer to process the same 256mb file when called from a website. The windows service is running under a domain account with administrator privileges.

The overhead in calling the WCF service is very fast yet the LoadFile method takes much much longer. I tried increasing the process priority during startup via

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess ().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
```

to no avail. I've run this service on a Win7 64bit desktop system (6gb), 2003 XP 32bit server (4gb) and 2008 R2 32bit server (4bg) all with similar results. The console and desktop apps each process the file in about 1min on the above system. The process does not appear to be memory constrained and entering swapville.

Are windows services somehow process constrained? Would I get better results running the WCF service under IIS?

**EDIT:** I tried calling the library directory from the website and that too takes 10x longer than the console or desktop application.

**UPDATE:** Turns out it was Log4PostSharp. The console and desktop apps didn't have any traces of log4net in the configuration files yet the website and windows service did. There was a log4net TraceAppender silently eating up precious CPU cycles.

Comment: How are you loading the file exactly? Did you try with a profiler to see where exactly the bottleneck is ( VS 2010 Ultimate contains a profiler )

Comment: I would recommend restoring the process priority class to normal if you have not already done so. Modifying the process priority will not typically speed up a program, and it could potentially create other problems.

Comment: @Davide: The profiler is also in Premium. +1; this is the way to go.

Comment: A Procmon trace might be enlightening, too.

Comment: @Davide we're stuck on VS2008 atm. @Jeffrey we have servers dedicated for the file processing so upping the process priority shouldn't be too much of a problem. That change was done to try and resolve the slowness which didn't help anyways.

Comment: When you run the console app is the file on the same server?  And when you run as a service, is the file on a different server?  Copying the large file across servers may be the bottle neck.

Comment: When you are running the console app, is it the same domain user under which the service is running?

Comment: Do you stress memory, e.g. by creating millions of short-lived string objects during the file processing? In that case small differences in how the GC behaves in a service process might result in large performance differences.

Comment: @Wim we're processing 3D files but in most cases we pre-calculate the space that's needed and allocate one large chunk.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot think why the behaviour you describe is happening - it does seem very strange. Since you are processing a relatively large file in memory though, the garbage collector may be affecting it. You could try changing the mode the garbage collector runs in to see if it has any effect.

The garbage collector has three modes - workstation, server and concurrent. Each one behaves in a different way and is optimised for different types of applications. Workstation mode is the default mode, and is what all processes run using unless configured to use something else. More info about the modes can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations.aspx).

Try explicitly setting the garbage collector to use server mode (it will only have an effect on a multi-processor machine though). To do this, put the following in your `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so far no luck with this change

Comment: I won't downvote you but a 10X slowdown due to the GC seems far-fetched. There are other areas to investigate first especially given the very small amount of info we have from the OP.

Comment: @Johann: I've experienced large slow downs before due to the garbage collector while it is garbage collecting - take a look at the `%time in GC` performance counter on a running application that is doing hard work.